# I need an image to take up the maximum space it can regardless of its original size

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I am developing a react-native application and I have a top bar and a bottom bar.  There is an image between these two bars, and I need it to take up the maximum space it can regardless of the images original size without getting in the way of the two bars.  I've been trying for a while and I can't figure out how to do this.

I have tried a bunch of things with flexbox and setting the image size, but I can't get it to work.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import Topbar from './topbar.js'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style = {{
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'space-between'
    }}>
    <View>
      <Topbar />
    </View>
    <View>
      <Image source={require('./image2.jpg')} />
    </View>
    <View>
      <Topbar />
    </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

// here are my bars

import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Image, StyleSheet, View, Text,Dimensions
} from "react-native";
import Animated from "react-native-reanimated";


const {screenwidth, screenheight } = Dimensions.get("window");

export default class Topbar extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <View style ={{
      width: screenwidth,
      height: 80,
      backgroundColor: "#C0C0C0",
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
    }}>
    </View>
  )
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  topbarbackground: {
    width: screenwidth,
    height: 80,
    backgroundColor: "#C0C0C0",
  }

})
```

I need to see the bars and the image and it has to take up the entirety of the phone screen.

Comment: your current `<Image />` doesn't seem to have anything going on. consider setting up your image as the background, using `<ImageBackground />`. do set a value for its height and width. you can also consider adding some top and bottom padding for your bars.

Comment: try https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#props-1

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am using a phone with a rather large screen. How can I adapt if it is being used by a phone with a smaller screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure what you are trying to get. You can try using `ImageBackground` component and set the `resizeMode` to `cover`. Example:

**Cover the entire Screen**

```
<ImageBackground 
    source={img}
    imageStyle={{ resizeMode: 'cover' }}
    style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
  <Topbar/>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}/>
  <Bottombar/>
</ImageBackground>
```

**Cover the available space**

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <Topbar/>
  <ImageBackground 
    source={img}
    imageStyle={{ resizeMode: 'cover' }}
    style={{ width: '100%', flex: 1 }}/>
  <Bottombar/>
</View>
```

Comment: Sorry, expo crapped out for a second.  Thanks!  I will try it now.

Comment: Sure, happy to help!